# Several views for one model?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

In my main window I have several user controls. One for the menu and one which has variable content depending on the menu choice. What is a good way to handle this with MVVM? Should both user controls have their own view models? But then how do I get the information from the menu view model to the content view model? Or should I use only one view model for the whole window?

This leads to a more general question: If I am using the same information in several places in my program, how do I handle that? How can two seperate views access the same model instance? Do I need to make that model static?

Comment: You can assign the ViewModel to the DataContext. Also using inheritance to give the ViewModel  a new name   public NewViewModel : CommonViewModel might work for you.

Comment: Don't make it static, inject your object into the views that need it.

Comment: Would recommend a view model hierarchy, then you can bind parts of the page to child view-models on your main view model.

Comment: H.B. has good advice.  Try to structure your view models are smaller classes that you compose together as properties on "larger" view models.  You may have a `MainFormVM` with a `Content` property that gets updated as menu items are picked.  Using a content control on the xaml and auto templates you can vary the UI through binding to match the subclass of the `Content` property.

Comment: @H.B.: Sorry, I'm relatively new to this. How do I inject an object? About the hierarchy: How can I make sure that the child view models are all the same instance?

Comment: In my opinion,  it's better to deal this scenario with parent and child view models.  ie MainWindowViewmodel,  MenuViewModel and ContentpageViewmodel.  Doing this will make it easier to manage the application since the entire section is divided into minor parts.

Comment: If you are creating a reusable usercontrols then you should have a seperate viewmodels for them.  They should be independent from your main window.  You interact with the usercontrol via properties, not its viewmodel.  Think ComboBox, you interact with it's properties and events, not the code behind that drives it.

Comment: @gartenriese: If you have new windows you usually construct them in code, then you can pass your existing view model to the constructor. If it's within a window you usually pass your view model to your views as `DataContext` via binding. Your child view models exist as properties on their parent view model, hence wherever you bind to said property on the parent, you bind to the same instance of the child view model.

Comment: @H.B.: Okay, so that's composition and inheritance combined? Never thought of that ...

Comment: @gartenriese: Usually there isn't that much inheritance, most of my view models inherit from a view model base class that implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` and such. Other uses of inheritance are very specific to the task at hand.

Comment: @H.B.: Oh okay, yeah I already got a base class. So it's actually just composition, i.e. the MainWindowViewModel has properties of all the children view models.

Answer (score -2):

> Should both user controls have their own view models?

Unless the controls in question are very process driven controls, it is best to have the controls work off of their declared [dependency properties](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2115888&seqNum=3) solely and not have indvidual VMs.

> same information in several places in my program, how do I handle that?

Don't overthink it, create one VM, initialize and place it onto the application as a static and then access it from other VMs which need it.

Then anywhere in the code one can get the running app via from the global [Application.Current Property (System.Windows)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev14.query?appId=Dev14IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(System.Windows.Application.Current);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true) which will have the static VM property which will hold the shared VM.